# Is there away to make CSS animations and gradients work across all browsers?

Tags: css-animations

I am currently trying to make my CSS3 animations work across most browsers but at the minute I am only getting it to work on web kit browsers.

Here is my code:

```
h1 {


font-family: 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;

font-size: 150px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-top: 50px;



background: #E9AB17 -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat ;

-webkit-background-size:  75px 200px;

color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

-webkit-background-clip: text;

-webkit-animation-name: shine;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
     text-align:center;


}
```

I have since added to code to and I am still having problems.

```
h1 {
font-family: 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;
font-size: 150px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-top: 50px;



background: #E9AB17 -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat ;
background: #E9AB17 -moz-gradient(linear,left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat ;
background: #E9AB17 -o-gradient(linear,left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat ;
background: #E9AB17 linear-gradient(linear,left top, right top, from(#e8a917), to(#f4b011), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat ;   



-webkit-background-size:  75px 200px;
 background-size: 75px 200px; /* Chrome, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, Opera, Safari 5+ */

 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;

-webkit-animation-name: shine;
-moz-animation-name: shine;
-o-animation-name: shine;
animation-name: shine;



-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-moz-animation-duration: 5s;
-o-animation-duration: 5s;
animation-duration: 5s;


-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite; 



     text-align:center;


}




@-webkit-keyframes shine
{
0%
{
background-position: bottom left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: top right;
}
}




@-moz-keyframes shine {
0%
{
background-position: bottom left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: top right;
}
}@-o-keyframes shine {
0%
{
background-position: bottom left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: top right;
}
}@keyframes shine {
0%
{
background-position: bottom left;
}
28%,100%
{
background-position: top right;
}
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-` is (as you might have guessed) a Webkit vendor prefix. You need to add in `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-` and no prefix.

Comment: I have tried this as I thought it would be the simple problem but for some reason it doesn't work and headings appear with no color.

Comment: I have copied all of the webkit elements and made new ones with the moz for testing. This didn't work so I then directly changed the webkit to just moz and tested it on firefox. Still got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

I guess thats probably what you need for the gradients.

as for animations
[here](http://css3please.com/)

For more information regarding CSS compatibility see
**[here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/)**